# как обратится к элементу массива через переменную

Tags: javascript, массивы

у меня есть функция

```
var array = [
    {
        'test1' : 1,
        'test2' : 2
    }
];

func(test1);

function func(attr) {
    array[0].attr
}
```

вылезает ошибка потому что он воспринимает 'attr' как элемент массива, как мне сделать чтобы можно было обращаться через переданный аргумент?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: вот тут кавычек не хватает вокруг тест1: `func(test1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По нулевому индексу вы получите свой объект с двумя атрибутами, обращайтесь через скобочную нотацию - так:

```
function func(attr) {
    array[0][attr]
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!!